# Package Will Not Update and System Will Not Upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, update-manager

Trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 (the updater offered the upgrade), when I click the Upgrade button, nothing happens and the updater exits. Trying from the command line there are no errors either until I noticed that there was a package that needed upgrading but I am unsure how to do it. Below are my attempts and I hope it's not too much information! I'm not sure what else to try so any ideas?

I was finally able to get a meaningful error so I've appended the command line text. Still no solution but an error is a place to start!

```
    $ sudo apt upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      libxnvctrl0 ubuntu-advantage-tools
    2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 784 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 2,331 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.0.2~20.04.1 [773 kB]
    Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libxnvctrl0 amd64 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [11.0 kB]
    Fetched 784 kB in 1s (987 kB/s)        
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    (Reading database ... 452762 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.0.2~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~20.04.1) over (20.3) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../libxnvctrl0_460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libxnvctrl0:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (440.64-0ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
    Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~20.04.1) ...
    Installing new version of config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf ..
    .
    Installing new version of config file /etc/ubuntu-advantage/uaclient.conf ...
    Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ua-reboot-cmds.servi
    ce → /lib/systemd/system/ua-reboot-cmds.service.
    Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ua-messaging.timer → /li
    b/systemd/system/ua-messaging.timer.
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    Processing triggers

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libxnvctrl0 ubuntu-advantage-tools
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 784 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,331 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.0.2~20.04.1 [773 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libxnvctrl0 amd64 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [11.0 kB]
Fetched 784 kB in 1s (987 kB/s)        
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 452762 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.0.2~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~20.04.1) over (20.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libxnvctrl0_460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxnvctrl0:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (440.64-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~20.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf ..
.
Installing new version of config file /etc/ubuntu-advantage/uaclient.conf ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ua-reboot-cmds.servi
ce → /lib/systemd/system/ua-reboot-cmds.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ua-messaging.timer → /li
b/systemd/system/ua-messaging.timer.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...

$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 143 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 452781 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing adobe-flash-properties-gtk (1:20201231.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libllvm10:i386 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...

$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo: do-release--upgrade: command not found

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ sudo update-manager
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libgegl-0.4-0/focal 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.22-3]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libgegl-0.4-0/focal 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.22-3]
libgegl-0.4-0/focal,now 0.4.22-3 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa]

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt --only-upgrade install 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa

$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa'

$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
    libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
    
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt autoremove
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
      adobe-flash-properties-gtk libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
    After this operation, 143 MB disk space will be freed.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    (Reading database ... 452781 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing adobe-flash-properties-gtk (1:20201231.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
    Removing libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libllvm10:i386 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
    libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
    
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo do-release--upgrade
    sudo: do-release--upgrade: command not found
    
$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    Release:    20.04
    Codename:   focal
    
$ sudo update-manager
    Checking for a new Ubuntu release
    Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
    
$ sudo apt update
    Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
    Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease  
    Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
    
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
    Listing... Done
    libgegl-0.4-0/focal 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.22-3]
    N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
   
$ sudo apt upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
    Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
    Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease  
    Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt --only-upgrade install 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
    
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob '1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex '1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa'
    
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt autoremove
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
    
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

There are the errors and it seems that in order to upgrade, something that is noit available needs to be installed:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libgegl-0.4-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libopenexr23 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install libopenexr23
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libopenexr23 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libopenexr24:i386 libopenexr24

E: Package 'libopenexr23' has no installation candidate

$ sudo apt-get install libopenexr24:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libilmbase24:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libilmbase24:i386 libopenexr24:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 677 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,770 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 libilmbase24 i386 2.3.0-6build1 [75.8 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 libopenexr24 i386 2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5 [601 kB]
Fetched 677 kB in 1s (1,003 kB/s)                                               
Selecting previously unselected package libilmbase24:i386.
(Reading database ... 452769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libilmbase24_2.3.0-6build1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libilmbase24:i386 (2.3.0-6build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libopenexr24:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../libopenexr24_2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libopenexr24:i386 (2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5) ...
Setting up libilmbase24:i386 (2.3.0-6build1) ...
Setting up libopenexr24:i386 (2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...

$ sudo apt-get install libopenexr24
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libopenexr24 is already the newest version (2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5).
libopenexr24 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libgegl-0.4-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libopenexr23 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libopenexr23
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libopenexr23 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libopenexr24:i386 libopenexr24

E: Package 'libopenexr23' has no installation candidate
```

Additional output based on comment:

```
$ apt-cache depends 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
E: No packages found

$ apt show 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa | grep Section:

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: No packages found
$ sudo apt remove 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa

$ sudo apt purge 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa

$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Output based on one answer:

```
$ sudo apt clean

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                  
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease                                        
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (133 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Added output from comment:

```
$ sudo apt-get -s install --reinstall libgegl-0.4-0=0.4.22-3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libgegl-0.4-0 [0.4.22-3] (0.4.22-3 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
Conf libgegl-0.4-0 (0.4.22-3 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
```

Comment: this is only a simulation `sudo apt-get -s install --reinstall libgegl-0.4-0=0.4.22-3` please show us.

Comment: Sorry, this comment got lost in the replies and comments below but I appended the question with the requested output. Thank you.

Comment: first of all I miss `focal-updates` in your packages sources. Please add this. and update your system.  and before you make a distro upgrade remove your ppa's especially the ppa a for gimp. `sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`  I do not know where the false dependence comes. `sudo apt reinstall libgegl-0.4-0=0.4.22-3`

Answer (score 2):

Check if any other packages depends on the 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa that can't be upgraded.

```
apt-cache depends 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa
```

Show the software repository of the 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa package that can't be upgraded. If this repository is a PPA that is no longer needed it can be removed with ppa-purge.

```
apt show 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa | grep Section:
```

The empty results of `apt show 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa` show that 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa is not installed. Delete the apt cache from `/var/cache/apt` .

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: That sounded promising but unfortunately did nothing useful that I can tell. I added the outputs to the question.

Comment: I replied to your comment by editing my answer.

Comment: Those are all things I had already tried but ran them again, posting the output to the end of my question. They did not help and still shows `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

Comment: Before Upgrading your os 1. remove all ppa entries first, 2. make sure you have upgraded to the latest packages in your current os version. 3. do your release upgrade 4. add and use ppa's for new os (if needed)

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually not a newbie and thought that's what I was doing but so far every machine I've tried to upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 has failed in one way or another but they generally give more specific error messages!

Answer (score 0):

None of the command line tools and functions seemed to work so I finally resorted to the GUI. By going to

*Software Updater->Settings->Ubuntu Software* and choosing *Main Server* instead of *Server for United States*,

then

*Software Updater->Settings->Other Software* and unchecking everything except *Conanical Partners*,

the upgrading ran as it should.